# Can I clone my hard drive into a better computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, disk-cloning

I'm buying a friend's old computer who has almost completely better specs than me (besides the GPU).

Would I have any problems just cloning my hard drive onto his 1TB hard drive, then just putting it into his computer and installing the necessary drivers?

Keep in mind, we have different parts and CPUs.

If this does not work, what steps should I take to switch over? Also what problems might I have if my current hard drive has Windows 7 and he has Windows 10?

Comment: Your Windows 7 installation cannot be migrated to the new computer since it’s an OEM license.

Comment: Presumably the newer computer is Windows 10, so collect your data from the old computer, move it to the new one and install upgraded apps (not the old legacy apps)

Answer (score 1):

> Would I have any problems just cloning my hard drive onto his 1TB hard drive, then just putting it into his computer and installing the necessary drivers?

There is third-party software that makes this process trivial.  Your real problem is the fact you will be unable to activate Windows 7 on the new hardware.

> If this does not work, what steps should I take to switch over?

Use one of the many third-party full disk imaging programs that specifically supports restoring to dissimilar hardware.

Windows 10 makes it trivial to either Reset the installation, or perform a Fresh Start, in either case the machine is restored to the same state (a fresh installation).

> Also what problems might I have if my current hard drive has Windows 7 and he has Windows 10?

The first major issue you will have once you restore your backup image to the HDD on this new machine is that Windows 7 will be unable to activate.  There really isn’t an appropriate solution to that problem.  Windows 7 is currently not sold by Microsoft and is also not supported.

There is also a good chance the new computer has a processor which will make it impossible to receive the current security updates through Windows Update.  Microsoft specifically prevented Windows 7, from receiving updates, when an unsupported processor was detected.

You will need to determine if that’s the case with this unspecified hardware and purchase a Windows 7 license.  However, your plan to use Windows 7, is really misguided since it really is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

While this wouldn't cause problems with some other Operating Systems, Windows is not designed to be capable to do this.

Windows in particular sets up it's system specifically for the computer it's on.  Switching out more than a few devices at a time will result in configuration headaches that exceed the effort of a fresh install.

Instead, I recommend backing up just your data portions.  You can also backup certain program directories if the program provides a tool to do so.  Steam provides a way to do this with the games you download through it.

I recommend you also keep a full back backup of the drive so that if something goes wrong or you forget something you can harvest the data out of that.

Comment: This information is outdated. Windows has been dealing with hardware changes pretty well since Windows 7 and improved with each release.